# Opening Remote Images to Use on GD2

Tags: ruby, gd

Is there any way to "open" remote images to be used on [`GD2`](http://gd2.rubyforge.org/)?

Comment: why not download it and then open just to make thing easier

Comment: @Viren: What's the best way to download the remote image to a temporary directory?

Comment: @Viren: Could you add that code into a answer so I can upvote and accept as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open approach would be to download the image in `tmp` directory and then open it using `gd2`

Here how you download the file from remote location to `tmp`

```
require "rubygems"
### Method 1
require "net/http"
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("image path")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
File.open("/tmp/a_#{Date.now}.png", "wb+") do |file|
  file.write http.get(uri.path)
end

### Method 2

require "open-uri"

File.open("/tmp/a_#{Date.now}.png", "wb+") do |file|
 file.write open("image path").read
end
```

Make sure the user has the permission to write in `tmp` directory